# Get Row Count Along With Table Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using the below SQL statement to get the row count and display all the columns I would like to have in the result set, courtesy [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/02/sql-magic-trick-getting-row-count-without-fetching-all-rows/)

Is this the best approach or are there any better and efficient ways of achieving the desired results

```
 SELECT mainsql.*
FROM (  SELECT t.*,
               COUNT (
                  1)
               OVER (
                  ORDER BY 1
                  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
                  row_count
          FROM (SELECT * FROM users) t
      ORDER BY 1) mainsql
```

Update 1

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT (*) OVER () AS row_count
  FROM users s
 WHERE (1 = 1 AND user_name = 'SCOTT')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query can be written simpler:

```
SELECT s.*, count(*) over () as row_count
FROM users s;
```

However, a faster query(does not need to count rows before fetching the result) and a bit different is:

```
SELECT s.*, rownum as row_number
FROM users s;
```

The last fetched row will contain the number of rows.
This may not help you(I don't know what you want to achieve) though.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is I need to get the total row count as well along with the database table columns. I have tried your first query and it is fine and faster however, when the where conditions are applied, count is still total count.

Comment: I have included my modified query as Update 1 in the question with where condition, however, row_count still showing the count of total rows in the users table. The where condition is generated dynamically by the framework which I am using.

Comment: You should add the column `COUNT (*) OVER () AS row_count` at the same level with your `where` condition. If the query is a subquery, the count will be computed before the where is applied.

Comment: @user75ponic if your `count(*) over ()` is showing the count for the entire table despite the where clause selecting a specific username, then we can only conclude that your username is the same across all rows. `count(*) over ()` means "get the count across all rows in the result set", so if you only have 5 rows in the resultset, it should return 5 (even if the table has 500 rows).